# How do you collect input and store it as a var in html

Tags: html

This is my short chunk of code and I'm trying to learn html and this seems right but it doesn't work. I'm not sure whats incorrect.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>
        Youtube Unblocker
    </title>
    <style>
        h1 {text-align:center;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#00ff80">

    <font color="white" size="7">
        <h1>Youtube Unblocker
        </h1>
    </font>
    <input type="text" id="urlLink">

    <button type="submit" onclick="getLink()">Submit</button>

    <script>
        function getLink() {
            var input = document.getElementById("urlLink")();
            alert(input);
        }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Variables are in Javascript, but not in HTML.

Try this please:

```
var input = document.getElementById("urlLink").value;
```